# How to add a object to another object

Tags: javascript

Hi say i have an object as below

```
{ID:'1',Name:'Some name',Notes:'NOTES'}
```

and another object as

```
{junk:'lll'}
```

I need the output as

```
{ ID: '1', Name: 'Some name', Notes: 'NOTES', junk: 'lll' }
```

Below is the code that i tried

```
var objIssues = [
{ID:'1',Name:'Some name',Notes:'NOTES'}
```

];

```
objIssues[objIssues.length] = {junk:'lll'};

console.log(objIssues)
```

The out put that i got is

```
[ { ID: '1', Name: 'Some name', Notes: 'NOTES' },
{ junk: 'lll' } ]
```

I'm stuck here any help regarding this will be much helpful.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?  You can use `$.extend(jsonIssues, {junk:'111'});` and `jsonIssues` will contain you other object.

Comment: JSON is a data serialization format and your question is not related to it. I've edited and re-tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var data1 = {ID:'1', Name:'Some name', Notes:'NOTES'};
var data2 = {junk: 'lll'};
var datakeys = keys(data2);
var i;

for (i =0; i < datakeys.length; i++) {
    var k = datakeys[i];
    data1[k] = data2[k];
}

console.log(data1);
```

Answer (score 2):

use [Jquery.Extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method

```
$.extend( object1, object2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,. hope this will work for you

```
 var data1="{ID:'1',Name:'Some name',Notes:'NOTES'}" ;
 var data2="{junk:'lll'}";
 data1=data1.concat(data2);
```

Comment: -1 you should at least try your code before answer a question http://jsfiddle.net/G8WLV/

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data1 = {ID:'1',Name:'Some name',Notes:'NOTES'} ;
 var data2 = {junk:'lll'}, key;
 for (key in data2) {
   if (data2.hasOwnProperty(key)) data1[key] = data2[key] 
 }
```